# ¿Como filtrar datos de un data frame en R?

Tags: r, datatable, filtro

Tengo un data frame (out.predict.garch) en , lo que quiero conseguir es filtrar los datos siguiendo la condicion de que las variables out.predict.garch$nombre sea igual a uno de los niveles (ibex) (eso si se hacerlo)  y que la variable out.predict.garch$error sea el valor mas pequeño , quedándome de esta forma con una única observación en el nuevo data frame.
He encontrado diversas formulas para filtrar data frame , subset , select, filtrer, pero en ninguno encuentro como se selecciona el valor menor de una variable numérica. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Sin un ejemplo reproducible es difícil responde. Hay varias formas de hacerlo, una opción podría ser usando la función `which.min()`:

```
out.predict.garch.ibex <- out.predict.garch[out.predict.garch$nombre=='ibex', ]
out.predict.garch.ibex[which.min(out.predict.garch.ibex$error), ]
```

Espero solucione tu inconveniente.

Answer (score 0):

Sin duda la respuesta de P. Paccioretti es la apropiada, pero de todas formas te ofrezco una aproximación al problema usando la paquetería incluída en `tidyverse`. Usar el pipe `%>%` mas los verbos de manipulación de datos, una vez que te acostumbras puede ser muy práctico, performante y tremendamente claro/legible.

Tu problema podría resolverse usando el "verbo" `filter`:

```
library(tidyverse)

out.predict.garch %>%             # a partir de out.predict.garch  
    filter(nombre == "DIA",       # filtramos por nombre == "DIA"
           error == min(error))   # y por aquellos dónde tenemos el mínimo error
```